# Error retrieving json data from external url and saving to mongoDB in python

Tags: python, web-services, mongodb

I need help saving json data retrieved from an external url to MongoDB in python.
   The code snippet I wrote to achieve that is pasted below. Any help will be appreciated. I am new on this site.

```
import urllib.request

import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)

db = client.test_database #database where I intend to store data

Collection = db.samplecollection # documents collection
#read data from url
readData = urllib.request.urlopen('some url that returns json data')
#store the data read to a variable ( I don't know if a document in Mongo is equivalent to an object or a complex type)
test = readData.read() # I confirmed data is being read
#save data to MongoDB
db.Collection.save(test) # when I try to save data to mongoDB I get an error

'''
 Error message
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EzempilloPythonScripts\readFdaData.py", line 8, in <module>
    db.Collection.save(test)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 282, in save
    raise TypeError("cannot save object of type %s" % type(to_save))
TypeError: cannot save object of type <class 'bytes'>
'''

print (test) # I can print the data
```

Answer (score 1):

read() gives you a string, and not a jsonobject. You have to parse it yourself.

I think the requests lib is better for this:

```
import requests

jsonobject = requests.get('url').json()
```

Here are te docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I think your `test` variable is a string, right?

You have to convert `json` format. It should be json format.

```
import json
test = '[{"_id" : 1, "name" : "HELLO"}, {"_id" : 2, "name" : "Happy"}]'
db.Collection.save(json.loads(test))
```